# Redis scan skipping keys

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

I'm using predis (with laravel if it makes any difference) php client to work with Redis.

I need to fetch all the keys from Redis that match certain prefix and I do it like this:

```
$keys = [];
    foreach (new Iterator\Keyspace($this->redis(), Cache::KEY_PREFIX.'*') as $key) {
        $keys[] = $rate_key;
    }
```

After the work with those keys is done, operation repeats - I'm getting those keys again in again in a loop. 
I noticed that after a few iterations some keys are not included in $keys array.

The strangest thing is that keys that disappear never appear in next iterations. Restart of the php process (it's a daemon) fixes the problem.

I'm using Redis 3.0.2 with Predis 1.0 and PHP 5.4

P.S. Within the loop over keys, I change values for some of them. I'm not deleting any keys, however.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed! That's because SCAN works that way, quoting from Redis documentation:

> However while blocking commands like SMEMBERS are able to provide all the elements that are part of a Set in a given moment, **The SCAN family of commands only offer limited guarantees** about the returned elements since the collection that we incrementally iterate can change during the iteration process.
>
> However because SCAN has very little state associated (just the cursor) it has the following drawbacks:
> **A given element may be returned multiple times. It is up to the application to handle the case of duplicated elements**, for example only using the returned elements in order to perform operations that are safe when re-applied multiple times.

So you may want to use want to use **[array_unique($keys)](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php)** after the `foreach`.

To understand why the iteration works that way the best thing is to read [**this part of the Redis documentation**](http://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-basic-usage).