# Laravel and redis scan

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5

I am trying to use redis `scan` with laravel. I can make a single request which returns 10 keys but I wish to loop until all the keys have been returned. I am unsure how to do this with laravel. Currently I have

```
$test = Redis::scan(0, 'match', '*keypattern*');
```

I don't know if there is a 'laravel' way of doing this.

**EDIT:**

I used composer to import `predis/predis` and got it working with

```
use Predis\Collection\Iterator;
use Predis;

...

$client = new Predis\Client([
    'scheme' => 'tcp',
    'host'   => 'localhost',
    'port'   => 6379,
]);

foreach (new Iterator\Keyspace($client, '*keypattern*') as $key) {
     $arr[] = $key;
}
```

but I would like to know the laravel way

**EDIT:**

var_dump of the single `Redis::scan`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "23"
  [1]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "key17"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "key72"
    [2]=>
    string(76) "key11"
    [3]=>
    string(19) "key73"
    [4]=>
    string(19) "key63"
    [5]=>
    string(19) "key87"
    [6]=>
    string(19) "key70"
    [7]=>
    string(19) "key65"
    [8]=>
    string(19) "key82"
    [9]=>
    string(19) "key43"
  }
}
```

Comment: Laravel uses Predis under the hood (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Redis/composer.json). Have you tried to call scan in a loop?

Comment: @martinczerwi I am at a loss of how to do that...

Comment: Short question because I can't reconstruct at the moment. `$test` from your first code sample should contain a cursor to iterate (like the native Redis call does). This is what you use on the next call to scan. Could you paste a var_dump of `$test`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the Redis facade passes commands directly to Predis (or Redis itself you might say), this goes hand in hand with the Redis docs (http://redis.io/commands/scan). You can use the cursor (first array entry) for subsequent calls to iterate until the cursor is zero.

I've put together a recursive approach, to scan all entries:

```
function scanAllForMatch ($pattern, $cursor=null, $allResults=array()) {

    // Zero means full iteration
    if ($cursor==="0") {
        return $allResults;
    }

    // No $cursor means init
    if ($cursor===null) {
        $cursor = "0";
    }

    // The call
    $result = Redis::scan($cursor, 'match', $pattern);

    // Append results to array
    $allResults = array_merge($allResults, $result[1]);

    // Recursive call until cursor is 0
    return scanAllForMatch($pattern, $result[0], $allResults);
}
```

Note that you might need to add `$this` before the recursion, if you use this in a class (would be `return $this->scanAllForMatch(...)`)

You would call it like that:

```
// Don't pass a cursor yourself!
$allResults = scanAllForMatch('*keypattern*');
```

Comment: You might also find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794866/redis-scan-skipping-keys

Comment: Thanks, works beautifully after a minor fix. And thanks for the heads up with the missing and duplicated keys.

Comment: Great, thank you too for the edit. I used `array_push` first, which takes the first param as reference, but the results where not what I wanted ;)

Comment: Had to change  ($cursor==="0") to ($cursor==0) to get it worked

Answer (score 13):

Thanks @martinczerwi
Here is a non-recursional version:

```
function scanAllForMatch($pattern)
{
    $cursor = 0;
    do {
        list($cursor, $keys) = Redis::scan($cursor, 'match', $pattern);
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            yield $key;
        }
    } while ($cursor);
}
```